# Python generate documentation using pydoc

Tags: python, pydoc

I have nested folder structure library and the question is about generating documentation from the source-code files.

## Folder Structure

```
  mylib
    ├── foo 
          ├── __init__.py
    │     ├── Foo.py
    ├── bar
    │     ├── __init__py
    │     ├── Bar.py
    ├── baz
    │   ├── qux
    │   │   ├── file1.py
    │   │   ├── file2.py
    │   │   ├── file3.py
    │   │   ├── file4.py
    │   │   ├── file5.py
    │   │   └── __init__.py
```

## Documentation

I was looking for a built-in solution (without downloading 3rd party plugins) to generate documentation for the python library and came across pydoc

**Documentation**: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html

from the documentation I rant this source file

`python3 -m pydoc mylib`

## Issue:

I have only one file generated mylib that lists 3 sub-directories as links

## Code

as per the request, here's a sample of code file.

```
class Foo:
    """
    :class: Foo

    A base `Foo` implementation.
    """

    def __init__(self, name: str = None, data: Any = None):
        """
        Constructor

        :param name: The name of the foo. Defaults to None.
        :type name: str
        :param data: The data. Defaults to None.
        :type data: Any
        """
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.data = data
```

Comment: it will be helpful if has some code to look at ?

Comment: updated question with some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pydoc` will treat sub-directories within your module as sub-modules and create links to them.

If I understand question correctly, then I think you only want to generate documentation for specific module,

If yes, then you can run `pydoc` on those specific module like:

```
python3 -m pydoc mylib.module1
```

Comment: Is there a way for pydoc to generate documents from the folder `mylib` and subfolders recursively? or do I have to run for each module?

Comment: unfortunately, pydoc does not provide an option to generate documentation recursively for the mylib  folder and its subfolders. In that case, you may need to use 3rd party plugins

Comment: so if I run pydoc for each module, I assume there will be no index for all these modules, like documentation linking all modules from it's index page.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Each module will have its own documentation page.

Comment: what 3rd party plug, do you use or recommend?

Comment: Sphinx. It allows you to generate documentation for an entire project(including multiple modules and submodules). (Note: I heard about it but I haven't used yet)

Comment: Any other documentation generator?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256597/discussion-between-suraj-sukale-and-appdeveloper).